# Верстка меню

Tags: html, css

Нужно сверстать такое меню:
Неактивные пункты окрашены в серый цвет с использованием градиента, активная владка имеет цвет основого блока с информацией- белый, а пункт, на который наведен курсор, становится выше остальных, как на картинке
[image]
Не получается выровнять текст в пунках меню по вертикали, `vertical-align` не работает.
Цвет выбранного пункта у меня не меняется на белый, нужен не пседокласс `active`, а что-то другое, но я не знаю что.
При наведении курсора высота пункта меню увеличивается вниз, а не вверх.
Пока что получается только так
[image]
Вот код, только там без картинок
http://jsfiddle.net/tUrHA/
Подскажите, как хотя бы приблизиться к тому, что я хочу получить?

Comment: Deonis, Большое спасибо!

Comment: Да не за что ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уж пардон за откровенность, но это свалка, а не CSS. Как-то бы упорядочили, что ли...
Оптимизировать за вас не стал, сделаете сами. [Смотрим пример для ваших закладок](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/tUrHA/3/)

Comment: То, что надо с изменением высоты пункта меню, спасибо за помощь!
Но цвет активной владки на белый в вашем коде не меняется :(
Не подскажите, что нужно в него добавить, чтобы это тоже было?

Comment: Вы используете Ajax? Или при клике страница перегружается? И по ходу пьесы, псевдокласс **:active** - это когда на ссылку нажимаешь, но это не значит, что она остается активной до тех пор, пока не нажмешь на другую.

Comment: Я пока еще не знаю Ajax, нужного эффекта средствами html и css можно добиться?

Comment: Да, я знаю, что псевдокласс :active  это не, что нужно.

Comment: А PHP вы тоже не используете? То есть у вас на каждой странице прописано это меню?

Comment: Нет, не использую. html и css хотелось бы по возможности обойтись.

Comment: В этом случае выход такой - на каждой странице в соответствущий ей элемент <li>, добавить класс (напр., active_link), в котором задать белый цвет. Добавлять надо так:

    <li class="about active_link">

Answer (score 0):

Используй line-height равный высоте блока. Будет по середине.